# What does "out" mean in this passage?

Tags: grammar

What does ***out*** mean in [this passage](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/books/2013/08/seamus-heaney-a-poet-of-in-between.html)?

> And it’s no accident that this selection of the best poems from three decades begins with the word “between,” for Heaney was a poet of the in-between (as his friend Helen Vendler has observed), writing from a zone somewhere between north and south, between Catholic and Protestant, between Ireland, England, and America, between formal and free verse, between public and private, between realism and allegory, and between plain speech and loading “every rift with ore,” while also balancing the gravitas of his subject matter with the frolic and grace of poetic language. As Heaney said, “***The point is to fly under or out and beyond those radar systems***.”

It is easy to understand "fly *under* the radar" and "fly *beyond* the radar"; but "fly *out* the radar" is ambiguous? Does it mean *to circumvent the radar* or what?

Answer (score 6):

You have to parse "out and beyond" together. In this case, "out and beyond" is used for emphasis, to signify a complete escape from the radar's detection.

Answer (score 2):

The implication is that radar has a defined range, both laterally and vertically. Flying *under* puts one outside of the range vertically.  Flying *out* put one horizontally outside the range.  In either case, one is *beyond* the range.

In either case, this is a metaphor for going beyond the expected.